# How do I repeat a portion of a background image

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, sprite

Is it possible to repeat-x and repeat-y just a specific portion of an image sprite? I can obviously separate the image into different files, but I was hoping there's a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Probably needs to be cut server-side.  You don't want to send a whole image just to use a piece of it client-side.  That makes mobile users angry.

Comment: Actually, the experts over at Sencha Touch base64 encode all of their iconography and bake it into the CSS, which is effectively the same thing. When we're talking about a total image size of 10kb, it's better to prefetch than worry about latency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not for background - CSS3 provdes this for [borders](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images). You can combine a tiled background with a sliced border to achieve the desired effect.
(Browser support is not complete, though)

Comment: This isn't precisely what I was looking for, but it's better than nothing. Thanks!